# ORA-00911: invalid character?

Tags: c#, xml, oracle

I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-00911: invalid character at  XDocument doc= Document.Load(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());*

With this code:

```
 using (OracleConnection conn1 = new OracleConnection(oradb1))
 {
     conn1.Open();

     using (OracleCommand crtCommand
         = new OracleCommand("SELECT dbms_metadata.get_sxml('VIEW','VIEW_TBL_A') FROM dual;", conn1))
     {
         XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(crtCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
         XNamespace ns = "http://xmlns.oracle.com/ku";

         if (doc.Descendants(ns + "COL_LIST_ITEM").Any(c => c.Attributes().Any()))
             MessageBox.Show("COL_LIST has value");
         else 
             MessageBox.Show("COL_LIST has no value");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the trailing semicolon.

```
using (OracleCommand crtCommand = new OracleCommand(
    "SELECT dbms_metadata.get_sxml('VIEW','VIEW_TBL_A') FROM dual", conn1))
```

Oracle doesn't like statement delimiters when passing in a single statement for immediate execution.