# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following java code for inserting values to the database

When i try the code below it works

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERT " +  "VALUES ('1', 'Simpson', 'Mr', 'Springfield', '2001')");
```

But when i try the code below i get an error

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERT (`USERID`, `FIRSTNAME`,`LASTNAME`,`EMAIL`,`PHONE`) VALUES ('2', 'james', 'john', 'myemail', 'myphone')");
```

Most of the answers provided here at stack overflow refer to a character misplacement of a semicolon  `;`. i.e. [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435756/error-java-sql-sqlexception-ora-00911-invalid-character) , [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728377/wheres-my-invalid-character-ora-00911), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116527/ora-00911-invalid-character) which does not seem to help me

Here is the full code of my class

```
package dbproject;

import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcconnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        java.sql.Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","data1","mypass");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERT (`USERID`, `FIRSTNAME`,`LASTNAME`,`EMAIL`,`PHONE`) VALUES ('2', 'james', 'john', 'myemail', 'myphone')");

        //st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERT " +  "VALUES ('1', 'Simpson', 'Mr', 'Springfield', '2001')");

        con.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){

                System.out.println(e);

        }
    }
}
```

What could be wrong with my execute query and what else could lead to the error?

Comment: what are the datatypes of your  Table ? Can you try using a Prepared Statement

Comment: Oracle does not use backticks as MySQL does

Comment: @juergend that is a great solution, never thought of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL and Oracle have some minor differences in their definition of an identifier. In MySQL, an unquoted identifier may begin with a digit, and double quotation marks are allowed in a quoted identifier; however, neither of these is allowed in an Oracle identifier. In MySQL, the quote character is the `backtick` (`). If the SQL mode ANSI_QUOTES is set, double quotes can also be used to quote the identifiers. In Oracle, identifiers are quoted using double quotation marks.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#i1026354

try;

```
   st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO USERT (USERID, FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,PHONE) VALUES ('2', 'james', 'john', 'myemail', 'myphone')");
```